# Can a declaration affect the std namespace?

Tags: c++, std, reserved

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

/* Intentionally incorrect abs() which seems to override std::abs() */
int abs(int a) {
    return a > 0? -a : a;
}

int main() {
    int a = abs(-5);
    int b = std::abs(-5);
    std::cout<< a << std::endl << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that the output will be `-5`and `5`, but the output is the `-5` and `-5`.

I wonder why this case will happen?

Does it have anything to do with the use of `std` or what?

Comment: Your implementation of `abs` is incorrect.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's the point. OP's asking why adding this broken `abs` affects `std::abs()`.

Comment: I've seen this before, and IIRC, declaring an unnamespaced `abs` like this is not allowed

Comment: Interesting, I get `5` and `5` with clang, `-5` and `-5` with gcc.

Comment: @Rakete1111 and in cmake is also `-5`and`-5`.

Comment: Cmake is not a compiler, but rather a build system. You can use cmake to build with various compilers.

Comment: I get -5 and -5 with Visual C++ 14 on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/WQO30452)

Comment: Datapoint: MSVC gives -5 and -5.

Comment: I'd probably have recommend you simply have your function `return 0` - that would've avoided having people think you unintentionally implemented the function incorrectly and made the desired and actual behaviour clearer.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Sounds like the clang behaviour would make a good follow-up question - it's not exactly expected either, is it?

Comment: @Bergi At least not to me just before :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The language specification [allows](http://eel.is/c++draft/headers#4) implementations to implement `<cmath>` by declaring (and defining) the standard functions in *global* namespace and then bringing them into namespace `std` by means of using-declarations. It is unspecified whether this approach is used

> **20.5.1.2 Headers**
>   **4** [...] In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (6.3.6) of the namespace `std`. It is unspecified whether these names (including any overloads
>   added in Clauses 21 through 33 and Annex D) are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit using-declarations (10.3.3).

Apparently, you are dealing with one of implementations that decided to follow this approach (e.g. GCC). I.e. your implementation provides `::abs`, while `std::abs` simply "refers" to `::abs`.

One question that remains in this case is why in addition to the standard `::abs` you were able to declare your own `::abs`, i.e. why there's no multiple definition error. This might be caused by another feature provided by some implementations (e.g. GCC): they declare standard functions as so called *weak symbols*, thus allowing you to "replace" them with your own definitions.

These two factors together create the effect you observe: weak-symbol replacement of `::abs` also results in replacement of `std::abs`. How well this agrees with the language standard is a different story... In any case, don't rely on this behavior - it is not guaranteed by the language.

In GCC this behavior can be reproduced by the following minimalistic example. One source file

```
#include <iostream>

void foo() __attribute__((weak));
void foo() { std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl; }
```

Another source file

```
#include <iostream>

void foo();
namespace N { using ::foo; }

void foo() { std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  foo();
  N::foo();
}
```

In this case you will also observe that the new definition of `::foo` (`"Goodbye!"`) in the second source file also affects the behavior of `N::foo`. Both calls will output `"Goodbye!"`. And if you remove the definition of `::foo` from the second source file, both calls will dispatch to the "original" definition of `::foo` and output `"Hello!"`.

---

The permission given by the above 20.5.1.2/4 is there to simplify implementation of `<cmath>`. Implementations are allowed to simply include C-style `<math.h>`, then redeclare the functions in `std` and add some C++-specific additions and tweaks. If the above explanation properly describes the inner mechanics of the issue, then a major part of it depends on replaceability of weak symbols for *C-style versions* of the functions.

Note that if we simply globally replace `int` with `double` in the above program, the code (under GCC) will behave "as expected" - it will output `-5 5`. This happens because C standard library does not have `abs(double)` function. By declaring our own `abs(double)`, we do not replace anything.

But if after switching from `int` with `double` we also switch from `abs` to `fabs`, the original weird behavior will reappear in its full glory (output `-5 -5`).

This is consistent with the above explanation.

Comment: as I can see in source of cmath there is no `using ::abs;` like for the `using ::asin;` so You can override the declaration, another point to mention is that the defined in std namespace functions are not declared for int but rather for *double*, *float*

Comment: From the view of the standard, the behavior is undefined per [\[extern.names\]/4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/extern.names#4).

Comment: But when I deleted the `#include<cmath>` in my code, I got the same answer.`

Comment: @Peter But then where are you getting std::abs from? -- It might be being included via another include, at which point you're back to this explanation. (It doesn't matter to the compiler if a header is included directly or indirectly.)

Comment: @Peter: `abs` can be declared in `<cstdlib>` as well, which might be implicitly included through `<iostream>`. Try removing your own `abs` and seeing if it still compiles.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you put the `using ::foo`: the "Goodbye!" definition is a redeclaration (and definition) of the same (overload of) `::foo` selected by the `using`.

Answer (score 13):

Your code causes undefined behaviour.

C++17 [extern.names]/4:

> Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

So you cannot make a function with the same prototype as the Standard C library function `int abs(int);`. Regardless of which headers you actually include or whether those headers also put C library names into the global namespace.

However, it would be allowed to overload `abs` if you provide different parameter types.

Comment: "or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace", so it cannot be overloaded in global namespace.

Comment: @xskxzr I am not sure about the interpretation of the text you quote;  if it is taken to mean that the user cannot declare anything of that name in the global namespace then the previous part of the text I quoted would be redundant, as would most of [extern.names]/3. Which leads me to think that something else was intended here.