# Can reserved function names be overloaded?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, reserved-words

This question is a follow-up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50898508/5376789).

Consider the following program:

```
#include <cmath>

// meaningless, only for language-lawyer purpose
void abs(void*) {}

int main(){
    abs(nullptr);
}
```

Does this program result in undefined behavior?

---

The related part in the standard is [[extern.names]/4](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/extern.names#4):

> Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, **or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace**.

I'm not sure whether overloading is permitted.

Comment: I don't know whether the behaviour is undefined, but it is certainly unexpected.

Comment: That's a weird paragraph. It starts with signatures, which is quite clear, and then segues to names.

Comment: @Ron `int abs(int);` is a *function signature from the C Standard library declared with external linkage*.  The non-bold text says this signature is reserved; but then the bold part goes on to say that the signature is reserved as a name, which makes no sense

Comment: Some "functions" are sometimes implemented as marcos - `htons` for example.  While not a "reserved" function that I know of, it highlights how poor some implementations can be.

Comment: @UKMonkey: C++ specifically says the C names which can be implemented as functions or macros have to be functions in C++. However, `htons` is not a Standard C function, which is why it's not covered by that rule.

Comment: Why would you **ever** want to do something like this?

Comment: @Walter there are a number of questions about overriding std::to_string() for custom objects I imagine this has similar motivations

Comment: @UKMonkey **Nope**. This question is **not** about overloading any methods in `std`. So your example doesn't apply.

Comment: @Walter *Yup*  If you seriously can't think of a function that would be of use to overload in global namespace, and you can't understand the word *"similar"* Then I don't see how you can say doesn't apply.   Maybe you mean "I can't think of any similar examples - could you give me one"?

Comment: @UKMonkey No, I cannot think about such a thing. A user should add **nothing** to the global namespace except `int main()`. All other stuff can happily live in an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @Walter Well don't ask questions if you don't want to know the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this statement, as it talks about names (from the C standard) that are reserved (for C++ implementations). In particular,

> Part 1:  Each function signature from the C standard library declared
>   with external linkage

This includes the C library function `abs`

> Part 2: is reserved to the implementation for use as a function
>   signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a name
>   of namespace scope in the global namespace.

So the name `::abs` is reserved for the C++ implementation. You can't use it. Overloading is irrelevant.

Comment: If it means the name `::abs` is reserved, then all the un-bold text in the original quote would be redundant. Not saying you're wrong but there still seems  to be some mystery about this paragraph.

Comment: @M.M: Names with "C" linkage don't live precisely in the global namespace, IIRC.

Comment: `abs` is not a function signature, so cannot be referred to in Part 1.

Comment: @M.M The un-bold text brings the constraint into non-global namespace. [This](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/qLaQUMHASIs) is a related discussion.

Comment: For some reason everyone skips p3: "Each name from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with `extern "C"` linkage, both in namespace `std` and in the global namespace."

Comment: @T.C. That seems very relevant. But I don't understand it really. Does this imply that `using namespace foo;` if `foo` contains, say, `abs(funny)` is illegal in the global namespace?

Comment: @T.C. Why is that relevant? I don't declare `abs` with C linkage.

Comment: @Walter: Why would that be the case? `using namespace Foo` only makes `Foo::abs` visible, it doesn't move `Foo::abs` to the global namespace.

Comment: The name is reserved for use by the implementation in (among other things) the global namespace. The use to which the implementation puts it is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr -
yes, you can

http://www.eel.is/c++draft/reserved.names#extern.names

Pulling in the rest of the context:

> 20.5.4.3.2: If a program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this Clause, its behavior is undefined.

And then also

> 20.5.4.3.3.2 Each global function signature declared with external linkage in a header is reserved to the implementation to designate that function signature with external linkage.
>
> 20.5.4.3.3.4 Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage,182 or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

These suggest you can, as it is only the signature that is reserved.

Bonus for namespace ::std

http://www.eel.is/c++draft/library#namespace.std

> 20.5.4.2.1.1  Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std  has summarised the exceptions

Comment: There was no question of adding to `namespace std`, but to adding to the global namespace.

Comment: @Walter if the standard states explicitly that std can not be extended, but then doesn't say anything about the global namespace; and explicitly states that it is the function signatures that are reserved - then adding new ones in the global namespace isn't rejected by the standard...

Comment: Do we need the part with `std` in this argumentation?

Comment: @Walter because the first parts suggest that you can overload any function in std too - which you can't, and I don't want this answer to suggest you can.

Comment: This is a red herring. The question clearly related to the global namespace (only).

Comment: But the specification says "or as a name". Note it says "as a function signature" in the first half part.

Comment: @xskxzr "or"  - used to link alternatives.  That means one OR the other.  If they're a function - they're reserved as a function.  If they're a name, they're reserved as a name.

Comment: But the subject is "each function signature". Well, I agree with you that this paragraph is weird, as StorryTeller pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925440/can-reserved-function-names-be-overloaded?noredirect=1#comment88850354_50925440).

Comment: @xskxzr To be honest, not doing so is by far the safest thing; the c++ standard has been changing so fast in recent years the whole of the global namespace could end up reserved soon, but that wasn't your question ;)